# On using NanoHTTPD, MediaPlayer showing Error (100,0)

Tags: android, video-streaming, media-player, nanohttpd

I am working on a video streaming application.On a server I have secured m3u8 files.Which contains encrypted ts files (AES-128 encryption).I am parsing the secure m3u8 file then I download the ts files & decrypt them.

I store all the decrypted files in device's external storage location.Then I create a new m3u8 file which points to all decrypted ts files.

I am using [NanoHTTPD](http://elonen.iki.fi/code/nanohttpd/) class to create my custom server on device itself & this points to a directory where I have put all my decrypted ts files & new m3u8 file.

Then I use a `VideoView` & I pass it a url of m3u8 file on my custom server.

When I start playing `VideoView` it starts video well but after sometime it shows an error message "Can't play this video"

In Log I get this message

```
01-15 18:53:52.072: W/AudioSystem(16009): AudioFlinger server died!
01-15 18:53:52.072: W/IMediaDeathNotifier(16009): media server died
01-15 18:53:52.072: E/MediaPlayer(16009): error (100, 0)
01-15 18:53:52.072: E/MediaPlayer(16009): Error (100,0)
01-15 18:53:52.072: D/VideoView(16009): Error: 100,0
```

I am not getting where is the problem.
In my Server or in VideoView.

I have checked all the encrypted ts files have been decrypted properly.
& I have played my custom server's m3u8 url to an Android player and it works perfectly.

I have also tried sample [m3u8 url](http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8) from apple,here I just download the ts files & create my own m3u8 file dynamically.It works fine.

Please guide me where & what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue.The problem was with the decryption.

Comment: How you set the key to VideoView Control ?